# Find parameters such as the mean for any distribution in R

Tags: r, documentation, distribution

Is there any documentation, inside R, on the parameters and CDF/PDF of the most common distributions? I tried `?rexp` but it doesn't provide the formula for the variance of X, only its mean.

Comment: I don't see that the mean is even given there. Try Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution ?

Comment: No. R is basically just a calculator. It assumes you know the stats. Those properties are better explained in a statistics text book.